# What servers are used mostly to host Angular 2 Apps in Production?

Tags: angular, server-side

What servers are used mostly to host Angular 2 Apps in Production. I have seen people used all sort of servers such as Heroku, Azure etc.

So I would like to know other than these which are most commonly used servers for hosting or running Angular 2 Apps.

Are we using WebSphere, WebLogic , tomcat aas well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use any server using you ease I have used nginx, tomcat and pm2 nodejs to host my application.

In all, you have to use a backend such as node, java server which will redirect  to application page else you will not able redirect to your page when refreshed